# import epochsecs w.r.t different baseline

Tags: amazon-redshift

I'd like to import some data into a Redshift database using `COPY`. For reasons passing understanding one of the columns in the data is a timestamp that's given in seconds since `2000-01-01 00:00:00`. Is there any way to turn these into proper timestamps on import?

Comment: `2000-01-01 00:00:00` is actually a proper timestamp. What is your problem in it? Detail more please.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clearer. The column in the data I'm importing is `int` and contains the number of seconds elapsed since `2000-01-01 00:00:00`. Ideally I would want to turn this column into a proper timestamp immediately on import, i.e. define the column as `'2000-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp + seconds_column * '1 second'::interval`.

Comment: How do you get the files in amazon s3?

Comment: They are deposited there by someone else and I have no control over the format the files are in.

Comment: In that case, create a temporary table which has the same format of data in file. Import the data into those temp tables and modify the data accordingly from that temp table, then insert into your original table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot transform data in a Redshift `COPY` load. I think you will have to stage these to a load table and then do the transform in the insert to the final table.

Worth noting though that you *could* do this if they had used the standard Unix epoch (seconds since `1970-01-01 00:00:00`) by adding `TIMEFORMAT 'epochsecs'` to your `COPY`.